# curl unable to access kubernetes services - error: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes

For some reason I'm unable to **curl** my service or pod exposing the service. Below setup used to work - not anymore.

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80

$ kubectl get svc,pods -o wide
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE    SELECTOR
service/nginx        ClusterIP   10.109.212.238   <none>        80/TCP    12m    app=nginx

NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-866795cfb8-ff5zv      1/1     Running   0          13m   10.47.0.2   nebula-web01       <none>           <none>
```

Getting application content from Service IP or Pod IP results with this error.

```
$ curl 10.109.212.238
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.109.212.238:80; No route to host

$ curl 10.47.0.2 
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.47.0.2:80; No route to host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough I discovered that the error appeared only on `nebula-web01` node. If I deployed the same application on different node e.g. `nebula-web02` and **curl** Service IP or Pod IP then the application returned its content. This made me think that there has to be something wrong with `nebula-web01` setup.

What fixed my problem was to restarting `docker` and `kubelet` daemon on `nebula-web01` node.

```sh
$ systemctl restart docker
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

## Notes

Additonaly, you might disable `firewall` and flush `iptables` according to [this instructions](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6139#issuecomment-251558161).

Answer (score 0):

First you might to do is describe your ingress:

```
> #kubectl describe ing [your-ingressname]
```

second, check your nginx deployment name:

```
> #kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces

deployment/nginx-deploy
```

make sure your run your ingress-resources and mention or link your service and use name: nginx-deploy, it should be the same.